# What is "calling queue"?

Tags: objective-c, ios

A newbie question, please bear with me. I cannot makes sense of what is a "calling queue". I search around but cannot find a definition. Maybe it's too simple to deserve a definition? For example, Apple document says the following completion handler is "invoked on the calling queue". Could anyone tell me which is the calling queue in the following code?

Edit: I am familiar with GCD and queue and thread concepts. Just not sure about the calling queue..

```
dispatch_async(DownloadQ, ^{
    //
    // Download (json to map to array)
    //
    NSArray* array = [DoubanDownloader downloadEvent];
    //
    // Map (Do NOT do this in main queue, will block UI)
    //
    [FillDatabase mapArray:array toManagedObjectsinContext:self.document.managedObjectContext byCommand:YES];
    //
    // commit changes to store 
    //
    [self.document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{  // This will get main thread!
        [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            // what's the calling queue?
        }];
    }];
});
```

Comment: The thread you call this method from.

Answer (score 1):

The calling queue is whichever queue makes the call to `saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:`. So e.g. if you call that from the main queue then your completion handler will also occur on the main queue.

So 'calling' is an adjective, rather than 'calling queue' being a compound noun.

Comment: Thanks Tommy.I think I understand now. Yet a related question: is "calling queue" related to "caller of the method"?

Comment: The caller will be the object that makes the call. So the calling queue will be whichever queue that object is operating on when it makes the call.

Comment: So which is the caller in this case?

Comment: The caller in a traditional sense is your anonymous block that you're executing via your managed object context.  Perhaps it helps to consider what's fundamentally happening - saveToURL: is calling dispatch_get_current_queue() in order to pick a queue to execute the completion handler on.  An alternative API would be for you to have provided a queue, but for whatever reason it doesn't do that.